# Unable to scroll to top of UITableView embedded in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have several **UITableViews** embedded in a **ScrollView**. The **ScrollView** scrolls from left to right or right to left, and the **UITableView** can scroll up and down. You scroll left or right to change tableview displayed to you. I turned off scrollToTop property in **ScrollView** and want that work in each of the **UITableView**.

However, I'm only able to turn on one of **scrollToTop** property in one table and the rest of table still won't scroll to top if you click on the status bar. If I turn scrollToTop on for each table in the ScrollView, then none of them would work. Is there a way to make all of the table work?

Comment: Are you changing the table view that has scrollToTop turned on as the user moves from one table view to the next? That would be required. Only one can respond to that touch at a time.

Answer (score 1):

[This is documented behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollsToTop):

> **Special Considerations**
>   On iPhone, the scroll-to-top gesture has no effect if there is more than one scroll view on-screen that has `scrollsToTop` set to `YES`.

If you're only letting one table view appear on the screen at a time, then you can set `scrollToTop` to `YES` for that table view and to `NO` for the others.

Another approach is to let `scrollToTop` set to `YES` for just the first table view, and set to `NO` for all the others. Then in the first table view's delegate, override `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` to return `NO` and to tell all the table views to scroll to the top using `setContentOffset:animated:`.